# RunTimeException android

Tags: android, android-listview, runtimeexception

My android app gives me this error from logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.RunTimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

this is my code:

```
package com.WNF;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Actiemenu extends ListActivity{

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView (R.layout.actiemenu);

final String[] array = new String[] {
        "Ding", "AnderDing", "Nogeending", "laatseding"
    };

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.actiemenu, array));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent een = new Intent(v.getContext(), Acties.class);
            startActivity(een);
        }
        else if (position == 1) {
            Intent twee = new Intent(v.getContext(), Acties2.class);
            startActivity(twee);
        }
    }
});
getIntent();
}
}
```

Any ideas what can be the problem??

Comment: @xandy are you sure? But why ?

Comment: @PareshMayani because ListActivity by default has a layout with that `id/list`. Of course, if you need to add anything else to it, you should use others suggested answers

Answer (score 2):

Place the `ListView` in your `main.xml` with id of

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import this

```
import your.package.name.R
```

in your case:

```
import com.WNF.R
```

This problem shows up when we import

```
android.R
```

instead of

```
package.name.R;
```

Comment: Is that answer related to the question? Will this help to clear the `RuntimeException`

Comment: because the error says "android.R.id.list". It could be one possible reason.